# How do I give a range of pages in a book index?

Tags: indexing, books

Indices in books sometimes refer to a range of pages, not just one page, for instance, like "arrangements to move to England 187-94". How can I do this in latex?

Comment: **Off Topic** Note some "house" styles specifically request they be shown as 187-194

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a range of pages by putting, for example

```
\index{indexentry|(}
```

on the first page of the range and

```
\index{indexentry|)}
```

on the last page of the range, where `indexentry` is the term you want to see in the index.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It works perfectly.